# How can I exclude a specific file before calling Remove-Item

Tags: file, powershell, powershell-4.0

The problem that I am having is inserting the `-Exclude` command into this script to help avoid file types like '.pst' or any others specified.  I am just now sure how to include the `$exclude` in the `Where-Object` Field.

```
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(2555)
$path = "\\File Path"
$log = "C:\Log output"
$exclude = ".pst"

# Delete files older than the $limit. <Use -WhatIf when you want to see what files/folders will be deleted before>

Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $limit} >$log

Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } >> $log

Get-ChildItem -Path $path  -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $limit}| Remove-Item -Force -WhatIf

Get-ChildItem -Path $path  -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } | Remove-Item -Force -WhatIf 

# Delete any empty directories left behind after deleting the old files. <Use -WhatIf when you want to see what files/folders will be deleted before>

Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -and (Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer }) -eq $null }  >> $log

Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -and (Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer }) -eq $null } | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse -WhatIf
```

Any Ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: This can be consolidated rather easily if need be. What PowerShell version do you have? You should have a look at `Tee-Object` for starters.

Comment: Why wait until `Where-Object`? Why not use `-Exclude` with `Get-ChildItem`. Is your last line removing empty folders?

Comment: I am using PSVersion 4.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your specific question you could add another clause into your `Where-Object` that looks at the file extension. Note this works because you have only the one extension. If you wanted to add more you would need to change the operator.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | 
    Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $limit -and $_.Extension -ne $exclude } > $log
```

However there are better options available that you should look at in your code. Letting the windows file system do most of the work instead of post processing with `Where-Object` could save you time and complexity. You can even combine your first couple of lines depending. Since you have v4 you can use the `-File` and `-Directory` switches to only pull those respective items.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force -File | 
    Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $limit -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit} | 
    Add-Content $log
```

While not exactly what your first couple of lines were doing I think it does what you meant it to do. Note the `-File` switch and combined date clauses.

If you wanted to log what you were removing you can also remove some repetition with [`Tee-Object`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849937.aspx) (Not the only way to address this)

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force -File | 
    Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $limit -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit} | 
    Tee-Object -FilePath $log | 
    Remove-Item -Force -WhatIf
```

I don't know where you need it but you can also just use `-Exclude` of `Get-ChildItem` to omit pst files.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -Exclude $exclude -Recurse -Force
```

Comment: This is very helpful.  I was looking at the way to use the exclude file type on any way possible that would be feesible.